# Show that every operator norm is consistent

Tags: normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, solution-verification

Is the following a correct way to show that operator norms are consistent?

$$
\|AB\|=\max_{Bx \ne 0}\frac{\|ABx\|_\alpha }{\|x\|_\alpha} =\max_{ Bx\ne 0}\frac{\|ABx\|_\alpha}{\|Bx\|_\alpha} \frac{\|Bx\|_\alpha}{\|x\|_\alpha}\le \max_{y \ne 0} \frac{\|Ay\|_\alpha}{\|y\|_\alpha} \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Bx\|_\alpha}{\|x\|_\alpha} = \|A\| \|B\|
$$
It shows that:
$$
\|AB\|\le \|A\| \|B\|
$$

Comment: Yep. Also see [here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT4350/h09/undervisningsmateriale/lecture7.pdf). If you are satisfied with this, I will convert this to an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof of matrix norm property: submultiplicativity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487855/proof-of-matrix-norm-property-submultiplicativity)

Comment: @AhaanRungta Tom Lyche is the lecturer of my course. I found the same proof in the slide you attached so I think this must be correct.

Comment: @copper.hat: The other question was intended for matrix norm which I think is not the same with operator norm

Comment: @dresden_p Nice! I'll convert to an answer.

Comment: @dresden_p: The term describing the above is submultiplicatve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, as demonstrated **[here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT4350/h09/undervisningsmateriale/lecture7.pdf)**.