# How can I prove submultiplicative of $p$-norm of matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How can I prove $$\|AB\|_p ≤ \|A\|_p \|B\|_p$$ where $$\|A\|_p = \max_{x≠0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}, \qquad p = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$ and known information below:

(i) $\|A\| ≥ 0$, with equality iff $A = 0.$

(ii) $\|cA\| = |c|  \|A\|$, for any $c ∈ \mathbb R.$

(iii) $\|A + B\| ≤ \|A\| + \|B\|$.

*Not duplicate of [Proof of matrix norm property: submultiplicativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487855/proof-of-matrix-norm-property-submultiplicativity), I don't know whats the connection between that answer an my question.

Comment: I have saw that, but I don't understand that, I mean, it's not p-norm in that answer.

Comment: I don't see connection between that answer and my question. @MartinR, the answer in that question may use some concept I don't know yet.

Comment: It holds for *any* matrix norm. Just write $||ABx||_p \le ||A||_p ||Bx||_p \le ||A||_p ||B||_p ||x||_p$ as in the other answer.

Comment: It is a duplicate. The linked question is about a general induced norm, of which the $p$-norm is a special case.