# about a lemma for the proof of submultiplicativity of matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

in the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487855/proof-of-matrix-norm-property-submultiplicativity): I don't understand how How $\|Ax\|\leq ||A|| ||x||$?

Comment: What is $x,X$? ${}{}$

Comment: I edited it. $x$ is a vector.

Comment: How do you define $\|A\|$?

Comment: $$\lVert A\rVert=\sup\limits_{\lVert x\rVert =1}\{\lVert Ax\rVert :x\in K^n\}$$

Comment: For non-zero $x $, we have $\|A (x/\|x\|)\|\leq \|A\|$.

Comment: So, if $x \neq 0$, then $\|A {x \over \|x\|} \| \le \|A\|$.

Comment: Note that this is **not** the submultiplicity referred to in the linked question! (It follows from the above, but it is different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|=1$. In particular, if $v$ an arbitrary vector (distinct from zero) in $\textsf K^n$ then we know that $\|tv\|=1$ where $t=1/\|v\|$.

So, $\|A(tv)\| \leq \|A\|$ and observe that $\|A(tv)\|=\|t(Av)\|=|t|\|Av\|=t\|Av\|$. In conclusion, we have
$$t\|Av\|\leq\|A\|$$
and then $$\|Av\|\leq\frac1t\|A\|=\|v\|\|A\|=\|A\|\|v\|$$