# Derivative of linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

Given $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $f(X)=X^TX$, how do I know that $df(A)H=A^TH+H^TA$ for $A\in O(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $H\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ where $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the orthogonal group.

Comment: This is true for all square matrices $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a function $\phi : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^k$ is differentiable at $x$ if there exists a linear map $L : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^k$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lVert \phi(x+h) - \phi(x) - L(h)\rVert}{\lVert h \rVert} = 0 .$$
In that case $L$ is uniquely determined and is written as $d\phi(x)$.

Given $X$, the map $L_X(H) = X^TH + H^TX$ is linear and we have
$$f(X + H) - f(X) - L_X(H) = X^TX + X^TH + H^TX + H^TH - X^TX - (X^TH + H^TX) = H^TH .$$
Thus
$$\frac{\lVert f(X + H) - f(X) - L_X(H) \rVert}{\lVert H \rVert} = \frac{\lVert H^TH \rVert}{\lVert H \rVert}$$
Since all norms on finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces are equivalent, we may assume that $\lVert - \rVert$ is a *submultiplicative* matrix norm (for square matrices) which means that $\lVert A B \rVert \le \lVert A \rVert \lvert B \rVert$. See for example [Proof of matrix norm property: submultiplicativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487855). Hence
$$ \frac{\lVert H^TH \rVert}{\lVert H \rVert} \le \lVert H^T \rVert$$
which goes to $0$ as $H \to 0$. This shows that $df(X) = L_X$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(X+\epsilon H) = (X+\epsilon H)^T(X+\epsilon H) = \underbrace{X^T X}_{f(X)} + \underbrace{(X^TH+H^T X)}_{f'(X)\cdot H}\epsilon + \mathcal O(\epsilon^2)
$$

Comment: How are you able to say $X^T H + H^TX = df(X)H$ from this equation?

Comment: @Cuhrazatee by definition, the directional (Gâteaux) derivative is given by $\frac{d}{d\epsilon}f(x+\epsilon h)|_{\epsilon=0}$, so its the linear term in the $\epsilon$-expansion

Comment: This only shows that the directional derivative exists, though, not that the total derivative exists. With this line of thought you can at most say that *if* $f$ is differentiable, it is of the above form. But to show total differentiability, you can use essentially the same technique: $f(X+H)=(X+H)^T(X+H)=X^TX+X^TH+H^TX+o(\vert H\vert^2)$. So applying this technique to get the directional derivative is going the long way around and missing the proof of existence.

Comment: Indeed, this is insufficient as @Vercassivelaunos explains. Though, in this case it can still be made to work with an extra argument: for any $H$, the directional derivative is $X\mapsto X^tH +H^tX$, which is continuous (indeed it is even the restriction of a linear map between finite-dimensional normed vector spaces). Hence, we can deduce $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable (this is the natural analogue of the classical theorem that continuous partials implies differentiability).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos total differentiability should be obvious since $f$ is just a multivariate polynomial function of degree 2.

Comment: @Hyperplane: I agree that it's obvious if you're looking at it with experience: it's a multivariate polynomial, or it's built out of linear operations, or its partial derivatives are continuous, or..., but from a pedagogical point of view, a reason should probably be given, since the asker is probably less experienced.