# How to find derivative of Multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am reading from multivariable calculus notes and need help with following:

Let $f : M(n,\mathbb{R}) \to M (n,\mathbb{R})$ and let $f(A)= AA^t$. Then find derivative of f,
denoted by df .

So, Derivative of f (df) if exists, will satisfy $\lim H\to 0 \frac{||f(A+H) -f(A) -df(H)||}{||H||} =0$.

In these kind of questions how should I find what df(H)  should be so that  it has to be used to check the definition of  derivative?

Should I go by guess work? What if there are more than 1 such df?

Comment: What you call the derivative is actually the *differential* of $f$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993446/derivative-of-linear-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try calculating $f(A+H)-f(A)$ and see what is left

$f(A+H)-f(A)= (A+H)(A+H)^t -AA^t= AA^t +AH^t + HA^t +HH^t- AA^t\\
=AH^t + HA^t +HH^t$.

The term $HH^t$ has norm $\|HH^t\|=\|H\|^2$ and so it will go to zero even when divided by $\|H\|$. Thus our candidate is

$df_{A}(H)=AH^t+HA^t$.

Now you can try and prove the limit is $0$ explicitly.

Comment: why can't there be any other candidate?

Comment: Can you please reply to my comment?

Comment: See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611254/proof-that-the-derivative-is-unique/611424